# Weird malloc bug in embedded software system when using OpenCV cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, malloc, heap-memory

We have encountered the weirdest bug, that we cannot account any possible explanations.
We have a embedded software system written in C++ and cross-compiled to arm processor from a linux ubuntu machine. It compiles everything into static binaries which is flashed onto the embedded processor which runs petalinux.
Now, let's say we have a function.

```
void test() {
    cv::Mat m1 = cv::Mat(100, 100, CV_64F);
    for (int i=0; i < 100; ++i) {
        for(int j=0; j < 100; ++j) {
            m1.at<double>(i, j) = -121.00;
            cout << m1.at<double>(i, j) <<endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "fullcout" <<endl;
    cout << m1 <<endl;
}
```

If in one file of the code, I call this function it runs without any problems. If I call it in a different file, I get

```
malloc: corrupted top size
```

And when backtraced in gdb.

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00000000008aba9c in raise ()
#1  0x0000000000400d34 in abort ()
#2  0x00000000008c8450 in __libc_message ()
#3  0x00000000008ce8b4 in malloc_printerr ()
#4  0x00000000008d1870 in _int_malloc ()
#5  0x00000000008d28dc in malloc ()
#6  0x0000000000459ddc in cv::fastMalloc(unsigned long) ()
#7  0x0000000000492184 in cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int) ()
#8  0x000000000041a8c0 in cv::Mat::create(int, int, int) ()
#9  0x0000000000419d54 in cv::Mat::Mat(int, int, int) ()
#10 0x0000000000402a24 in test() ()
#11 0x0000000000421e70 in Coordinator::process(std::shared_ptr<SyncedData>) ()
#12 0x0000000000421ce8 in Coordinator::pollLoop() ()
#13 0x0000000000417ff4 in main ()
```

We are using OpenCV4.x cross-compiled using aarch64-gnu toolchain provided by the repo.

Sorry we don't have a minimum reproducable example. But given the symptoms please share what could it be based on your intuition.

Thanks.
Love all

Comment: Maybe the problem could be generated by other section of the code?

Comment: The error indicates that some other prior operation overwrote parts of the heap it wasn't supposed to, e.g. out-of-bounds of an allocation. It doesn't need to have anything to do with the shown function.

Answer (score 0):

You say "static binaries".

If that is shorthand for binaries statically linked to the C runtime I think the problem is that one of the shared objects B.so has allocated memory which has been passed to another shared object A.so. A.so does some work and then tries to deallocate the memory.

The problem is that the memory belongs to the heap from B.so.

The solution is to deallocate the memory in B.so.